No questions found. perhaps you'd like to select a different tab? - On the Questions tab
Refreshing the page on Worldbuilding a few minutes ago, I was surprised to encounter this:

I'd no filters engaged, nor was I changing tabs, just refreshing as stated.
This resolved on another refresh of the page and delivered the expected "Questions" tab contents.
I'm jut putting this here assuming that it's a temporary glitch, perhaps a few bits lost in transit and won't repeat - so this post is for reference of anyone encountering this in future and should anyone wish to investigate.
Related: "Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" - but relating to the "featured" tab and was 13 years ago.

Yeah, happens to me once in a while, looks like it happens when a cache is being rebuilt. (server side.) Anyway as for tags, there's no error message, it's a bug with the questions list being sometimes empty or not up-to-date.
